# How to manipulate value based on textbox value?

Tags: javascript, html

If I enter `negative value` in textbox, while in `onclick` the value will be *reduced by some other value*.

If I enter `positive value` in textbox, while in `onclick` the value will be *add by some other values*.

Comment: what did u try so far?

Comment: i am trying to reduce the values when user enter the negative values.   example:in text box i enter "-3" while on click it reduce the -3 units with another text box value that i entered.

Comment: cool, where are the codes that you are having trouble with? :)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple comparison.

```js
function go() {
    var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById("value").value),
        positiveValue = 5,
        negativeValue = -1;

    value += value < 0 ? negativeValue : positiveValue;
    document.getElementById("value").value = value
}
```

```html
<input id="value" onchange="go()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of the textbox comparing it on button click.

***HTML :***

```
<input type="text" id="inputTextBox" />

<input type="button" id="changeButton" value="update value"/>
```

***javaScript :***

```
var paddingValue = 10;
document.getElementById("changeButton").onclick = function(){
    var inputTextBox = document.getElementById("inputTextBox");
  if(inputTextBox.value < 0){
    inputTextBox.value = parseInt(inputTextBox.value) - paddingValue;
  }else{
    inputTextBox.value = parseInt(inputTextBox.value) + paddingValue;
  }
};
```

[***jsFiddle demo***](https://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/qmy3nw8k/)